# JavaScript regex, start sentence on capital letter only in between periods

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm trying to get my regex to return the right substring of a paragraph text. I've determined that the best thing to do would be to pull in any sentence which comes between two periods, and which begins with an uppercase letter only (no numbers or punctuation).

What I have so far returns every other sentence between two periods (not sequential sentences), and also I can't figure out how to grab a sentence that only begins with a capital letter.

Here's the expression:

```
var bodyStr = result.body;
var truncatedStr = bodyStr.match( /[^\.!\?]+[\.!\?]+/g );
```

I'm using regex101 to try and make the second part of this work (pulling sentences that begin with capital, non-number, non punctuation characters) and it breaks:

https://regex101.com/r/rJ8sC5/1

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the capital letter to your regex:

```
/[A-Z][^\.!\?]*[\.!\?]+/g
```

Comment: Btw. this covers only ascii capital letters.